# Can I send user notification after someone calls the user in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have just started to learn notifications in Flutter.

What I want to do is when someone calls user, I want to check callers number if it is not saved, send user some notification.

I can check if the caller's name is in contacts, but when user opens my app. Is there a way to make flutter app work in background, and whenever call happens my app checks if it was unsaved contact call, and if it was send user a notification.

Does someone how to achieve such thing?

Comment: just do it in background service . 
[link](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes)

Comment: thanks for information. I will check it out